# how to show response data in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i have following code but my page does not show data...;( i don't now why please help me, i am new in angularjs. I AM calling web API its working fine console log show json record,  but in my page record does now show... why

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <script src="Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script>
  var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    app.controller('customersCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
        $http.get("http://localhost:9000/employees").then(function (response) {
            $scope.myData = response.data;
        });
    });


    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="customersCtrl">
        <br>
       <p>Today's welcome message is:</p>
        <!--<h1>{{myWelcome}}</h1>-->
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="x in myData">
            <li ng-repeat="x in myData">
                {{ x.ProductName }} ',' {{ x.ProductDescription }}
            </li>
                <!--{{ x.ProductName + ', ' + x.ProductDescription }}-->
            </li>
        </ul>


    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

result = `[{"ID":1,"ProductName":"xcxc","ProductDescription":"xcxc","UnitPrice":2323,"QtyAvailable":23}]`
its show below error in chrome console log

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:9000/employees. No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: Did you get error in console?

Comment: no....every thing working fine , console log , show json data,but my page record does not show

Comment: you must be accessing your json in worng way

Comment: try print FirstName alone first

Comment: i am edit my post check

Answer (score 0):

```
      <li ng-repeat="x in myData">
            {{ x.FirstName }} ',' {{ x.LastName }}
      </li>
```

Comment: Please add some explanation of why this code helps the OP. This will help provide an answer future viewers can learn from. See [answer] for more information.

Comment: @Jerry What link would that be?

Answer (score 0):

All the things are fine in your code, might angular not loaded or http not responded correct:

```js
     var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
     app.controller('customersCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
       $scope.myData = [{
         FirstName: "firts1",
         LastName: "last1"
       }, {
         FirstName: "firts2",
         LastName: "last2"
       }, ];
     });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.20/angular.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="customersCtrl">
    <br />
    <!--//  <p>Today's welcome message is:</p>-->
    <!--<h1>{{myWelcome}}</h1>-->
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="x in myData">
        {{ x.FirstName + ', ' + x.LastName }}
      </li>
    </ul>


  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<li ng-repeat="x in myData">
 {{x.FirstName}}, {{x.LastName}}
</li>
```

Comment: Please add some explanation of why this code helps the OP. This will help provide an answer future viewers can learn from. See [answer] for more information.

Answer (score 0):

We have to use JSONP to prevent the cross origin policy.

```
var url = "http://localhost:9000/employees?callback=JSON_CALLBACK";

$http.jsonp(url)
    .success(function(data){
        console.log(data);
    });
```

or

If you want to disable policy then follow below steps

For Windows... create a Chrome shortcut on your desktop.
Right-clic > properties > Shortcut
Edit "target" path :

```
"C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --args --disable-web-security
```

Then try with your existing code