# How to show response after calling this.http.post

Tags: angular

```
   this.http.post(URL, formData, options)
    .map(res => res.json())
    .catch(error => Observable.throw(error))
    .subscribe(
      data => console.log(data.message),
      error => console.log(error)
    );
```

The data that I see in chrome developer tools is 
Successfully upload the file for processing

I want to show the data on a html element, div or li for example in angularjs2. I followed the link

[how to show response data in angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40131009/how-to-show-response-data-in-angularjs)

and I was hoping that angular2 would resolve the below code that is written in component.html.

```
<div>
  {{data.message}}
</div>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: where is data being assigned to a member instance variable?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
In your component

```
this.dummyService.create(this.beautifulObject)
    .subscribe(myObject => {
        this.objectAfterCreation = myObject;                        
});
```

In your service

```
this.http.post(URL, formData, options)
    .map(res => res.json()) //you can add your data type here .map(res => res.json() as beautifulObject)
    .catch(error => Observable.throw(error));
```

In your template

```
<div *ngIf="objectAfterCreation">
    {{ objectAfterCreation.message }}
</div>
or
{{ objectAfterCreation?.message }}
```